# Is it possible to insert an Image within a SuperScript?

Tags: html, mathml

I was wondering if it's possible to use an `<super>` & `<sub>` script tags & embed an Image within them ?!

Comment: You mean `<sup>`. There is no tag `<super>`.

Comment: Yes, I mean <sup> & <sub>   Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't have images in [MathML](http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml3/mathml3.dtd). You can have images in [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml3/mathml3.dtd): IMG is a special, specials are inline, and sup/sub allow inlines.

Comment: mglyph may be used to include arbitrary images in pure mathml, or if you prefer, using html+mathml (as defined in html5 for example) you can use an html img element within a mathml mtext.

Answer (score 0):

You must be more precise. These are html tags, not script tags, and are not MathML. There are MathML `<msup>`, `<msub>`, and `<msubsup>` tags. You can put `<img>` elements inside html elements, or probably inside a mathml `<mtext>` element (the MathML spec would say it's outside its scope to specify whether or not this is legal, but I would think yes), and you can put `<mtext>` inside `<msup>`, `<msub>`, or `<msubsup>` elements.

Comment: the mathml spec says it is out of its scope to specify how html elements work, but advises people defining combined formats to allow the host language in mtext (and other token elements) and that is what HTML5 explicitly does.<mtext><img.... is conformimg html5.